# Android: PsiFile not parsed?

Tags: android

I don't know why, but when I opened my project with Android Studio, an error message suddenly popped up like this.

```
5:21:18 PM IllegalStateException: cannot reset configurable: PsiFile not parsed for file /Users/marshall/Documents/Projects/Messenger/build.gradle. Wait until onPsiFileAvailable() is called.
```

Can someone explain what this message means? Also, here's the `build.gradle` file.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is the `settings.gradle` file.

```
include ':app'
```

**Added**

Here's another called titled 'IDE Fatal Errors'. It says that Exception in plugin Android Support. 5 minutes ago. occurred once since the last clear.

Details:

```
cannot reset configurable: PsiFile not parsed for file /Users/marshall/Documents/Projects/Messenger/build.gradle. Wait until onPsiFileAvailable() is called.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: PsiFile not parsed for file /Users/marshall/Documents/Projects/Messenger/build.gradle. Wait until onPsiFileAvailable() is called.
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.parser.GradleGroovyFile.checkInitialized(GradleGroovyFile.java:194)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.parser.GradleBuildFile.getValue(GradleBuildFile.java:84)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.editors.AndroidProjectConfigurable.reset(AndroidProjectConfigurable.java:175)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.AndroidProjectStructureConfigurable.reset(AndroidProjectStructureConfigurable.java:337)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.ConfigurableCardPanel.reset(ConfigurableCardPanel.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.ConfigurableCardPanel$1.compute(ConfigurableCardPanel.java:80)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.ConfigurableCardPanel$1.compute(ConfigurableCardPanel.java:65)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:962)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.ConfigurableCardPanel.create(ConfigurableCardPanel.java:65)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.ConfigurableEditor$1.create(ConfigurableEditor.java:70)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.ConfigurableEditor$1.create(ConfigurableEditor.java:67)
    at com.intellij.ui.CardLayoutPanel.createValue(CardLayoutPanel.java:87)
    at com.intellij.ui.CardLayoutPanel.select(CardLayoutPanel.java:115)
    at com.intellij.ui.CardLayoutPanel.select(CardLayoutPanel.java:100)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.ConfigurableEditor.<init>(ConfigurableEditor.java:115)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.SettingsDialog.<init>(SettingsDialog.java:52)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowSettingsUtilImpl.editConfigurable(ShowSettingsUtilImpl.java:215)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowSettingsUtilImpl.editConfigurable(ShowSettingsUtilImpl.java:194)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.AndroidProjectStructureConfigurable.doShowDialog(AndroidProjectStructureConfigurable.java:219)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.AndroidProjectStructureConfigurable.showDialog(AndroidProjectStructureConfigurable.java:211)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.actions.AndroidShowStructureSettingsAction.showAndroidProjectStructure(AndroidShowStructureSettingsAction.java:78)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.actions.AndroidShowStructureSettingsAction.actionPerformed(AndroidShowStructureSettingsAction.java:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ChameleonAction.actionPerformed(ChameleonAction.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:191)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter$1.run(ActionMenuItem.java:312)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:958)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:282)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:110)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setPressed(JToggleButton.java:308)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at com.apple.laf.ScreenMenuItemCheckbox.itemStateChanged(ScreenMenuItemCheckbox.java:193)
    at java.awt.CheckboxMenuItem.processItemEvent(CheckboxMenuItem.java:389)
    at java.awt.CheckboxMenuItem.processEvent(CheckboxMenuItem.java:357)
    at java.awt.MenuComponent.dispatchEventImpl(MenuComponent.java:351)
    at java.awt.MenuComponent.dispatchEvent(MenuComponent.java:339)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:761)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:857)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:658)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:386)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```